# is it possible to mount Windows file shares on Chromebook

Tags: windows, samba, chromebook

I have a cisco e4200 router that exposes my media library as windows file shares.
Is it possible to access them from my Chromebox?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that Chromebooks have any native file sharing capabilities.  The best way would be to use a NAS with a web-based interface that will allow you to transfer files, or use a cloud service.  There are also utilities that will allow you to set up a windows or mac to offer web-based file sharing.

Look [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromebook-central/VrYwSNH9i1w) for more detailed info