# How can I access files on Windows Server from a Chromebook?

Tags: windows, google-chrome-os, network-drive, chromebook

Is there anyway to access a network drive (ntfs) on a Windows server from a ChromeBook?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/545429/is-it-possible-to-mount-windows-file-shares-on-chromebook?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

You could use Network File Share for ChromeOS (from Google).

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/network-file-share-for-ch/ndjpildffkeodjdaeebdhnncfhopkajk?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You could log in to the server from an browser plugin giving you remote access through a program like LogMeIn and access the network drive.